# Implement Euclidean division to write greatest common divisor of two positive integers in terms of a linear combination of those integers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write a program that can write the greatest common divisor of two positive integers in terms of those integers. For example, let's say I have the numbers 353 and 15, I would find the gcd using the following steps:

353 = 23*15 + 8

15 = 1*8 + 7

8 = 1*7 + 1

7 = 7*1

so the gcd is 1. I have implemented this as:

```
//div_algo always takes int1 >= int2
int div_algo(int int1, int int2)
{   
    if (int2 == 0) //we are done
        return int1;
    int factor = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    factor = int1/int2; //this is useful for linear combination
    remainder = int1 % int2;
    return div_algo(int2, remainder);
}
```

The problem is, if I want to find the linear combination, I basically work backwards. So, continuing with my example:

1 = 1*8 - 1*7 (substitute 7 = 15 - 1*8)

1 = 1*8 - 1*15 + 1*8 = 2*8 - 1*15 (substitute 8 = 353 - 23*15)

1 = 2*353 - 46*15 - 1*15 = 2*353 - 47*15

and there we go. The problem I am experiencing is that I don't know how to "store" the previous equations so that I can back substitute.

Comment: Look up the "Extended Euclidean algorithm", this is exactly what it's for.

Comment: You don't need to "store the equations", just the numbers. Either of two approaches: (1) assign the return value of the recursive call to a variable, and do something with it "on the way out". (2) do you know of any data structures in C++ that might be used to store integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another parameter that will store the factors you are looking for. You can implement it like this:

```
int div_algo(int int1, int int2, vector<int>& factors)
{   
    if (int2 == 0) //we are done
        return int1;
    int factor = 0;
    int remainder = 0;
    factors.push_back(int1/int2); //this is useful for linear combination
    remainder = int1 % int2;
    return div_algo(int2, remainder, factors);
}
```

Note the use of `&` for factors. You don't want to copy the array, but just send along a reference to the same original array. You can replace `int` in the vector with a struct that can keep whatever data you consider necessary.

To call it you can do:

```
vector<int> factors;
div_algo(353, 15, factors);
for (int x : factors) cout << x << " ";
```